# Setting Up Chrome on Public Computers

Tags: google-chrome, google-accounts

I'm looking for a way to automatically delete Google Accounts on a public computer. We have a few PCs and a few Macs in a library. Students are using GAFE accounts and it's becoming annoying to have to "delete" the account after signing out.

Is there setting or preference that would allow the account to automatically be removed from Google's login page? Obviously someone would need the password to actually access the accounts, but we'd prefer not to have them listing previous users of the computer.

I know that a user can delete themselves from a computer but I'm looking for a way to automate the process when they sign off their account.

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/internet-related-filtering-firewall/111836-google-chrome-gpo-settings.html Just disable the service

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Chrome Settings

Go down to People

Select "enable guest browsing"
Deselect "let anyone add a person to chrome"

That's what worked for me, or seems to be working...